# Android how to set imageviews side by side in listview's headerView

Tags: android, imageview, listings

I am wanting to do networkImageViews side by side placing in listview's headerview. networkImageViews sizes are custom. One of them is 40dp other is 50 dp. etc... When it comes to end of the screen it will expand underline.

Sample https://camo.githubusercontent.com/397c91d68dc6e496f194391481fa3a4408bb83f1/687474703a2f2f7331312e706f7374696d672e6f72672f727279376c773837372f53637265656e73686f745f323031355f30395f32395f32315f31375f35332e706e67

This link is using TextView but i want to do it with imageView. How can i do ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for [StaggeredGridLayoutManager](https://inducesmile.com/android/android-staggeredgridlayoutmanager-example-tutorial/)

Comment: I'M wanting to do this horizontaly. When screen bound exceeded, it will continue underline.